# Avoid line breaks around anonymous functions when reformatting code

Tags: php, phpstorm, code-formatting

I'm working with PHP in IntelliJ 2017.3 (Same issue in PhpStorm). And I can't find an option in the Code Style to solve this issue I'm having.

When reformatting it makes a line break on both sides of the anonymous functions.

```
$collection
    ->map(
        function ($val) {
            return $val;
        }
    )
    ->each(
        function ($val) {
            return 'nope';
        }
    );
```

But I would like to keep the function declaration and closing brace inline.

```
$collection
    ->map(function ($val) {
        return $val;
    })
    ->each(function ($val) {
        return 'nope';
    });
```

Is there some setting I'm missing? :)

Comment: Mine seem to behave how you want it by default, I do have to manually insert a line break before the `->` I've set mine from PSR-2 in settings > code style > PHP > set from menu

Comment: The line break before `->` isn't the problem, it's the line break before `function` :/
I don't mind formatting the code as I want it, I just want it to stop messing it up ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to:

> Settings > Editor > Code Style > PHP > Wrapping and Braces >
> Function/constructor call arguments > New line after '('

Uncheck if checked, should be better.

Comment: Awesome! For some unknown reason, my example pane didn't want demonstrate that rule. It just kept wrapping no matter what O.o

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I wasn't sure. I just checked and it does work (in PHPStorm 2020.2).

Comment: @Tabbernaut Yeah that was a typo, was about to post a screenshot, but glad you found it.